# How to use hadoop from spark thrift server?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, thrift, beeline

Please consider the following setup.

hadoop version 2.6.4

spark version 2.1.0

OS CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

All software is installed on a single machine as a single node cluster, spark is installed in standalone mode.
I am trying to use **Spark Thrift Server**.
To start the spark thrift server I run the shell script
`start-thriftserver.sh`

After running the thrift server, I can run beeline command line tool and issue the following commands:
The commands run successfully:

```
!connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000 user_name '' org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
create database testdb;
use testdb;
create table names_tab(a int, name string) row format delimited fields terminated by ' ';
```

My first question is where on haddop is the underlying file/folder for this table/database created?
The problem is even if hadoop is stopped using stop-all.sh, still the create table/database command is successful,
which makes me think that the table is not created on hadoop at all.

My second question is how do I tell spark where in the world is hadoop installed?
and ask spark to use hadoop as the underlying data store for all queries run from beeline.

Am I supposed to install spark in some other mode?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My objective was to get the beeline command line utility work through Spark Thrift Server using hadoop as underlying data-store and I got it to work. My setup was like this:

```
Hadoop  <-->  Spark  <-->  SparkThriftServer  <--> beeline
```

I wanted to configure spark in such a manner that it uses hadoop for all queries run at beeline command line utility.
The trick was to specify the following property in spark-defaults.xml.

```
spark.sql.warehouse.dir hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse
```

By default spark uses derby for both meta data and the data itself (called warehouse in spark)
In order to have spark use hadoop as warehouse I had to add this property.

Here is a sample output

```
./beeline
Beeline version 1.0.1 by Apache Hive
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000 abbasbutt '' org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/abbasbutt/Projects/hadoop_fdw/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/abbasbutt/Projects/hadoop_fdw/apache-hive-1.0.1-bin/lib/hive-jdbc-1.0.1-standalone.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Connected to: Spark SQL (version 2.1.0)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 1.0.1)
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000>
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000>
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000>
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> create database my_test_db;
+---------+--+
| Result  |
+---------+--+
+---------+--+
No rows selected (0.379 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> use my_test_db;
+---------+--+
| Result  |
+---------+--+
+---------+--+
No rows selected (0.03 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> create table my_names_tab(a int, b string) row format delimited fields terminated by ' ';
+---------+--+
| Result  |
+---------+--+
+---------+--+
No rows selected (0.11 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000>
```

Here are the corresponding files in hadoop

```
[abbasbutt@localhost test]$ hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/
17/01/19 10:48:04 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 4 items
drwxrwxr-x   - abbasbutt supergroup          0 2017-01-18 23:45 /user/hive/warehouse/fdw_db.db
drwxrwxr-x   - abbasbutt supergroup          0 2017-01-18 23:23 /user/hive/warehouse/my_spark_db.db
drwxrwxr-x   - abbasbutt supergroup          0 2017-01-19 10:47 /user/hive/warehouse/my_test_db.db
drwxrwxr-x   - abbasbutt supergroup          0 2017-01-18 23:45 /user/hive/warehouse/testdb.db

[abbasbutt@localhost test]$ hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/my_test_db.db/
17/01/19 10:50:52 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 1 items
drwxrwxr-x   - abbasbutt supergroup          0 2017-01-19 10:50 /user/hive/warehouse/my_test_db.db/my_names_tab
[abbasbutt@localhost test]$
```